# How to fix SQL syntax error with updated_at in nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, nestjs

I has netjs application, when i make some action, i received error:

```
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' `updated_at` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `id` IN (3)' at line 1
```

My `updated_at` has format: `2021-05-17 12:45:02.204105`.

Column in my nestjs application has code:

```
@CreateDateColumn()
created_at: Date

@UpdateDateColumn()
updated_at: Date
```

Where can be a problem and how i can fix this error?

Comment: Provide complete query text which produces this error. The problem is posessed immediately before citated code part.

Comment: What database are you using? Is it SQL Server?